# android - shake detection

Tags: android, shake, vibration, android-vibration

I use [this good library](http://jarofgreen.co.uk/2013/02/android-shake-detection-library/) for detect shake motion on android devices.
Everything is good! But on my phone (Sony Xperia P) receiving SMS cause my phone to vibrate and shake detected!
In some other phone like HTC Sensation XE, the problem doesn't exist.
Any suggestion?
Thanks is advance.

Comment: Is there some kind of API or Listener an App can use to see whenever another App triggers the shake? If there is, there should be a nice clean solution to this. If not, I can't think of an easy solution!

Comment: Vibration just make very fast accelerations in some axis. Is it possible to ignore them? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacing `SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER` with `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` in `sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor` solved my problem!
The `SensorManager.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER` has been deprecated in API level 3 ([Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER)).

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be caused by the difference of sensor sensitivity across mobile devices. Your Xperia has presumably more sensitive sensor than the HTC. You can check this by setting your detection to be less agressive.

Doubling `MINIMUM_EACH_DIRECTION` in `ShakeDetectActivity` class should do the job.